# Identify NSURLSession in completion block

Tags: ios, swift, subclassing

I want to identify a session within my `didFinishDownloadingToURL` method:

```
func URLSession(session: NSURLSession, downloadTask: NSURLSessionDownloadTask, didFinishDownloadingToURL location: NSURL)
{
    if (session.sessionType == EnumImageRequestSession)
    {

        // I want to check with sessionType, but NSURLSession does not have
        // any such property. How to add this type property while creating the session?
    }
    if (session.sessionType == EnumAudioRequestSession)
    {

    }
}
```

How to achieve this? Should I create a subclass of `NSURLSession` and add a `sessionType` property?

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few options that I have used in the past.

1. When you start the NSURLSession, you can add it to an Dictionary or Set with a key value associated to the Session. When it completes, find the Session using it's identifier in the Set, and then you will have your associated key.
2. You can check the URL associated with the session.

Option 1 is my tried and true method so far, using a Set.

Comment: Yes you are right .these may be solution.But I am trying to create a subclass of NsUrlSession and add a property (sessionType). now I create new session with new subclass which is of nsurlSession subclass and assign new value to  added property (sessionType). and I am assuming when delegate will call then I will check added property with session (returned in didFinishDownloadingToURL method) . but when I create a new session with new subclass app crashed . Please suggest Can we do this with creating a subclass of nsurlsession by adding a propery?

Answer (score 1):

As `NSURLSession` is an `NSObject` subclass, you can use an Objective-C associated object, and by doing so you avoid doing housekeeping of for instance a map of sessions by type that you would otherwise manually have to create.

Here's a short example (where I'm cutting some corners with forced unwraps I actually would not in production oriented code):

```
import Foundation
import ObjectiveC

enum SessionType:Int {
    case Audio
    case Image
}

func someFunctionWhereYouCreateTheSession() {
    let session:NSURLSession = NSURLSession()
    objc_setAssociatedObject(session, "sessionType",
                             NSNumber(integer:SessionType.Audio.rawValue), objc_AssociationPolicy.OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN)
}


func URLSession(session: NSURLSession, downloadTask: NSURLSessionDownloadTask, didFinishDownloadingToURL location: NSURL)
{
    let sessionType:SessionType = SessionType(rawValue:(objc_getAssociatedObject(session, "sessionType") as! NSNumber).integerValue)!

    switch sessionType {
    case .Audio:
        print("foo")

    case .Image:
        print("bar")
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for reply .I will try this .Please suggest Can we not do this with creating a subclass of nsurlsession and adding a propery to subclass. and when delegate method calls back then we check addded propery with session object returned in delegate method ?